# debugging move_uploaded_file in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

I am using move_uploaded_file to upload files in cakephp, this was working for a while, but suddenly it broke. (I don't seem to see any recent changes in svn that relate to this issue, so I can't just revert them).

The problem is, move_uploaded_file is returning false, but it isn't telling me what's wrong. I tried doing:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

but it isn't accomplishing anything. No errors are being reported.

```
if (!file_exists($folder_url . '/' . $filename))
{
    // create full filename
    $full_url = $folder_url . '/' . $filename;
    $url = $rel_url . '/' . $filename;
    // upload the file
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    $success = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $url);
    $result['success'] = $success;
    $result['debug']['url'] = $url;
    $result['debug']['full_url'] = $full_url;
    $result['debug']['file'] = $folder_url . '/' . $filename;
}
```

Hosting server is in ubuntu server 9.10 running LAMP, development machine is windows 7 running XAMPP

EDIT:

I changed the activate error reporting to before the upload and it still doesn't work:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$success = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $url);
```

In Cakephp Config:

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
Configure::write('log', E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

EDIT 2:

I did a scandir on $rel_url and it shows up the files just fine

```
[test2] => Array
    (
        [0] => .
        [1] => ..
        [2] => 1.jpg
        [3] => 10.jpg
        [4] => 16.jpg
        [5] => 2.jpg
        [6] => 2010-12-12-0142065.jpg
        [7] => 22.jpg
        [8] => 3.jpg
        [9] => 4.jpg
        [10] => 5.jpg
        [11] => 6.jpg
        [12] => 7.jpg
        [13] => 8.jpg
        [14] => 9.jpg
        [15] => error.png
    )

[debug] => Array
(
    [url] => img/recipes/555.jpg
    [rel_url] => img/recipes
)
```

Comment: You need to activate error reporting **before** the call to `move_upload_file`! Or simply set Cake's debug to >0.

Comment: Silly question, are you sure you file is been uploaded? ['error']=0

Comment: Yeah, it is being uploaded for sure, error code is 0. I have a lot more of code around what I posted that checks for all kinds of other errors, I omitted them here for brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that there were updates in Subversion. I think that you did an `svn checkout` or `svn update` that messed up the permissions on the directory that you are trying to upload to. Check your permissions.

BTW: move_uploaded_file() is a native PHP function. This has nothing to do with CakePHP.

Comment: Oh, I know that move_uploaded_files is native php, I mentioned cakephp in case that cakephp is hiding the error messages or something.

I just checked permissions it seems that all users have full control in the folder in windows, and it is chmod 777 on the linux server, so that shouldn't be the problem =/

Comment: @Razor Storm: Have you tried Deceze's suggestion of setting debug to something larger than 0 in the Cake configuration?

Comment: Yeah, I edited my question to provide more details: Configure::write('debug', 2);

Answer (score 0):

If file is been uploaded, and that the directory is 777, it might be that the paths are not correct.

Did you try to put a file in your target directory, and check with file_exists, if your $url is correct?

I had another problem once with the file filename. I don't remember exactly all the details, but it had to do with accented character in the filename.

EDIT

try with absolute url, that's what I do

```
$url = WWW_ROOT.'img/' . $filename;
```

Comment: I did a scandir on $rel_url and it shows up the files just fine. The filename is 555.jpg so should be ok as well.     

[debug] => Array
        (
            [url] => img/recipes/555.jpg
            [rel_url] => img/recipes
        )

Ahh the format got screwed up, see my edit up there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the directory owner is `www-data` ? try :

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /your/upload/folder/
```